Salesforce is ignoring the first argument in IF statement
Kindly check what is missing in this formula.
I'm using it in the Summary Formula column (I'm calling it as Net value):
IF(Opportunity.ChannelPartner__c = 'ABC Company',
OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT:SUM,
OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT:SUM - CDF1:SUM)


Opportunity.ChannelPartner__c is the name of the 3rd party company (this is from the Grouping Field)
OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT:SUM is the current year value of an opportunity
CDF1:SUM is a row-level formula that I added which computes for the commission amount of either 15% or 10% depending on the 3rd party company (first year value * 15% or 10%)

The issue is that it ignores the first argument.
It will only apply the second argument: first year value less commission amount, to all 3rd party accounts regardless if it meets the condition.
I tried putting first year value less the commission amount as the first argument and first year value as the second argument and got the same result, it will ignore the first argument and will apply first year value to all of the 3rd party accounts.

Welcome to SFSE and thanks for your question. To help with this, what type of field is the ChannelPartner__c field? Is this text, or a lookup field?

thank you. its a lookup field. i also used the IF statement to compute the commission amount (CDF1:SUM) so that some accounts will get 15% rate while others 10% and it worked fine.

You have a period in ABC Company., that will throw off your results.

The reason you are facing is due to the fact that a Lookup field doesn't store the text value you are expecting, but instead stores the ID of the record that is being referenced.
For this logic, you'll either need to include create a Text formula field on Opportunity that provides you the text of the name of the Account or you may need to create a new Custom Report Type to ensure that you can use the Account Name field, rather than referencing the ChannelPartner__c lookup.

I used the same lookup field in the row level formula and it worked:
IF(Opportunity.ChannelPartner__c='ABC Company', OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT0.15,  IF(Opportunity.ChannelPartner__c='X Company', OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT0.15, IF(Opportunity.ChannelPartner__c='Z Company', OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT0.15, OpportunityLineItem.FirstYear__c.CONVERT0.10))).

This probably works because you removed the period from ABC Company

Sorry for that. I edited the IF statement in question by removing the actual company name which has a period at the end and replaced it with ABC Company but forgot to remove the period. I'll edit that to avoid confusion. thank you.
